# How to avoid referencing the same index in an array (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, element

I am having problems with my arrays in Java.  I am using arrays in classes as class fields, which are all static since I do not instantiate the class.  I call an array like so (btw this is an array of objects, 'Customer' is its own class):

```
 public static Customer[] cDatabase = new Customer[MAX_DATABASE];
```

Where MAX_DATABASE is a constant representing the maximum number of entries.  BUT what happens is when I type:

```
 className.cDatabase[0].firstName = "John";
```

(avoiding using methods just for simplicity)
That value is adjusted, but every firstName field in every other cell in the array also changes.  I am sure this has everything to do with the way that I called the array, but when I do this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<className.MAX_DATABASE; i++){
      className.cDatabase[i] = new Customer();
 }
```

After declaring the fields like this:

```
 public static Customer[] cDatabase;
```

But then I get nullpointerexception.  What is the best way to get this array working properly so the elements do not point to the same index of an array?
I'm sure the correct answer also avoids NPE...

Comment: looks like there's a big problem with the design of the code to me. Either you tell what exactly you're trying to achieve or post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/‏). And welcome to stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do both. Create a new array and put new Objects into that array.

```
public static Customer[] cDatabase = new Customer[MAX_DATABASE];
for(int i = 0; i<className.MAX_DATABASE; i++){
      className.cDatabase[i] = new Customer();
}
```

Comment: Also consider `Arrays.fill(cDatabase, new Customer());`

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano Wouldn't that place the very same `Customer` in all array slots?

Comment: Yes, it would; it may be correct or incorrect depending on the rest of the app, and how the array is used.

Comment: This is helpful, but another user was able to point towards the actual issue.  Either way, I wasn't doing this properly and I thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `firstName` field itself is not declared `static` in your `Customer` class, otherwise it will will only ever hold one possible value.

```
class Customer {
  private String firstName;
  ...

}
```

Also using public fields is not good design in general. Consider using getters & setters for these fields. The same applys to the `cDatabase` array field itself.

Comment: This appears to be the solution.  However since my S&Gs were designed to deal with `static` variables, I just have to change them up a bit.
I also avoided using S&Gs in my example to make it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

If all `firstName` change for every cell then things can be two:

- you declared `firstName` as `static` in `Customer` class and ignored the warning that states that you should access it in a static way
- you are assigning the same Customer instance to all elements of the array

eg

```
Customer[] array = new Customer[MAX];
Customer c = new Customer();
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
  array[i] = c;
```

Here all elements of the array point to the same `Customer` so you always modify and get the same one from every cell.

What you should do is something like:

```
Customer[] array = new Customer[MAX];
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
  array[i] = new Customer();
```

In this way you create `MAX` distinct instances of `Customer`. Modifying one won't affect the others.