# Setting Array element changes all elements with same name

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a follow-on post to the link below. I received help there that showed my code works as expected on jsfiddle, so there must be a concept I am not understanding when creating nested arrays and pushing objects to them:
[Updating elemint in JSON updates ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231397/updating-elemint-in-json-updates-all)

This question sounds like the exact issue, although in javascript for me, I am having but I cannot interpret how to apply the correct answer to my use case:
[How to avoid referencing the same index in an array (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096495/how-to-avoid-referencing-the-same-index-in-an-array-java)

This ordering UI is a little unorthodox where they select the accounts first, and then when they select any product after that, it has to be added to all accounts.

My Array is JS:

```
runningOrdfers = {
"id": 1402846607011,
"status": "unsaved",
"accounts": [
    {
        "compid": 919759,
        "compname": null,
        "products": [
            {
                "BCINUM": "539504",
                "ITEMUNIT": "EA",
                "ORDERDETAILS": [
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69230",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69231",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "SHIPPINGCOMMENTS": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "compid": 920001,
        "compname": null,
        "products": [
            {
                "BCINUM": "539504",
                "ITEMUNIT": "EA",
                "ORDERDETAILS": [
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69230",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "SHIPDATEID": "69231",
                        "SHIPPERIODID": "2096",
                        "QUANTITY": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "POTEXT": "",
                "SHIPPINGCOMMENTS": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is how I create and append objects to the array. First, create a new order:

```
var runningOrders = {};

function createNewOrder(event) {
    var uniqueID  = uniqueIdentifier();
    var accounts = [];
    var products = [];
    runningOrders.id = uniqueID;
    runningOrders.status = "unsaved";
    runningOrders["accounts"] = accounts;
    runningOrders.accounts["products"] = products;
    selectAccountsTab(event);
}
```

Then add the accounts to the order:

```
    function addAccountToOrder(compID) {
    getAccount(compID);
    var thisAccount = {};
    var n = savedAccountByCompID.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var accountListObject  = savedAccountByCompID[i];
        thisAccount.compid = +accountListObject.COMPID;
        thisAccount.compname = +accountListObject.COMPNAME;
        thisAccount.products = [];
        runningOrders.accounts.push(thisAccount);
    }   
}
```

And finally add products to the accounts in the order just created:

```
    function setProductSelected(bcinum){
    var thisProductSelected = {};
    var thisProduct = "bcinum" + bcinum;
    var thisProductData = productData[thisProduct];

    thisProductSelected.BCINUM = thisProductData.BCINUM;
    thisProductSelected.ITEMUNIT = thisProductData.ITEMUNIT;
    thisProductSelected.ORDERDETAILS = [];

    thisOrderDetails = {
        SHIPDATEID: "69230",
        SHIPPERIODID: "2096",
        QUANTITY: ""
    };
    thisProductSelected.ORDERDETAILS.push(thisOrderDetails);

    thisOrderDetails = {
        SHIPDATEID: "69231",
        SHIPPERIODID: "2096",
        QUANTITY: ""
    };
    thisProductSelected.ORDERDETAILS.push(thisOrderDetails);

    var a = runningOrders.accounts.length;
    for (var ii = 0; ii < a; ii++) {
        currAccount = runningOrders.accounts[ii];    //possible problem? Loping over accounts and pushing same object?
        currAccount.products.push(thisProductSelected);
    }
}
```

My function to iterate and update the elements for the index I navigate to:

```
function updateComments(compID,bcinum,comment) {
    var accounts = runningOrders.accounts;
    var n = accounts.length;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (accounts[i].compid == compID) {
            var p = accounts[i].products.length;
            for (ii = 0; ii < p; ii++) {
                if (accounts[i].products[ii].BCINUM == bcinum) {
                    accounts[i].products[ii].SHIPPINGCOMMENTS = comment;
                }   
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

When I call my update function, it is updating the SHIPPINGCOMMENTS at all index locations instead of just the one I wanted to be updated, which is based on compID:

updateComments(919759,539504,'sooner');

Comment: This code is almost unreadable, What are this... vars? are you trying to avoid `Object.prototype`? Why? There is a lot of examples which don't seem to have context to this question. Can you provide a jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net example that others can debug? Finally, Consider using forEach/map functions the nested for loop is really hard to comprehend with this usage example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of readbility issues this seems to work as designed as shown in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sikope/1/edit?js,console). It would seems there is something else going on.

This is a great example of how immutability can help a great deal. Designing your code around immutable data structures can alleviate complexity and confusion with where *truth* is. It is unfortunate that in JavaScript (by default) objects are managed by reference not by value so immutable objects are not directly supported by the language itself. Newer versions (ECMAScript 5) support the `Object.freeze` but you would need a polyfill in older / dysfunctional browsers.

To manage the complexity of a deeply nested data structure it could help to encapsulate the data in a custom objects (object as defined in classic object oriented design, although in the case of JavaScript this would be a prototypical object). However, this is beyond the scope of the original question (see this blog post on [prototypical object oriented design](http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/guide)).

Comment: Thanks @Sukima. I am obviously not a seasoned JS developer and will look into your suggestions. The jsbin and jsfiddle from the previous post work as expected and it was suggested to me there to provide more code. Since the issue appears to lie with how I am creating and populating these data structures, that is why I provided the additional code. So the brief issue is when I run `updateComments(919759,539504,'sooner');`, both the indexes at `accounts[0].products[0].SHIPPINGCOMMENTS =sooner` AND `accounts[1].products[0].SHIPPINGCOMMENTS =sooner`get updated which is unintended.

Comment: Both would be updated if the products on both accounts reference the same object. Again JavaScript passes objects by reference. Your *creation* code is probably reusing objects instead of creating new ones so you think you have two but really you have one and that is why it seems they all change.

Comment: Thanks @Sukima. After going through and implementing objects and closures, I still had the same issue. In my code I listed above, there was a couple of lines that I thought might be the culprit originally: `currAccount = runningOrders.accounts[ii];    //possible problem? Loping over accounts and pushing same object?
currAccount.products.push(thisProductSelected);` My temporary solution is to make a copy of the deep nested object by using JSON.parse as shown here: `var thisInstance = "data" + ii;
var thisInstance = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thisProductSelected));` and then pushing that.

Comment: In our department, the moment any of us come up with a workaround like that we are promptly hit with a cattle prod and sternly told "fix the problem don't just work around it".